# Google Play Game Services connection issues handling

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm currently developing a multiplayer card game (4 players) using Unity, and I'm using GPGS for multiplayer purpose.
One thing that I can't figure out is connection problem handling. For now I deployed a system that every five second each player send a message to other players telling them i'm online. If a player doesn't send any messages for 10 seconds, I'll consider him/her having connection issues.
My first question is: Is this the right way? I couldn't find anything other than OnPeerDisconnected in GPGS documentation, and I assume it's not related to this.

My second question is: Sometimes while playing the game, one or some of user(s)' gets timed out. In other words, they don't get any message and can't receive any. All my 4 devices are connected to the same network, and network quality is good. How's possible that one of four players encounter network problem?

My last question: I don't know when GPGS consider a player to be timed out? For testing purposes, one time before using the method I explained above, I disconnected one of players, and waited for 5 minutes. Nothing happened. Also I don't know if the user can come back to game (resume playing) after a long time (20-30 seconds) or not?

Thanks for your help. Sorry if anything is ambiguous.